# How can I remove absolute paths from the stack trace?

Tags: go

How can I remove absolute paths from the stack trace?

For example, now:

```
main.main()
    /home/userName/WORKSPACE/temp/mvps/main.go:16 +0xb2
```

And I want it to be something like this:

```
main.main()
    main.go:16 +0xb2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the `GOPATH` prefix, add the following flags when you run `go build` ([*ref*](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13809#issuecomment-168874760)):

```
go build -gcflags=-trimpath=$GOPATH -asmflags=-trimpath=$GOPATH ...
```

If `GOPATH` is not set in your environment, `$(go env GOPATH)` is still likely to work (thanks to Flimzy for pointing this out):

```
go build -gcflags=-trimpath=$(go env GOPATH) -asmflags=-trimpath=$(go env GOPATH) ...
```

Comment: i would say that this is something very wanted for those that must spare disk usage regarding logs in a server..

Comment: @Victor It’s a surprisingly awkward solution - you’d think there would be a better way of doing this. I have a shell alias set up to include those every time.

Comment: is not awkward to my eyes @MTCoster. You may use a Makefile to build your project, placing the flags (and any aditional config in there) once for all.

Comment: How to do this in Go 1.14? All examples I found use this obsolete method.

Comment: Ehm.. why not just use the -trimpath flag? "go build -trimpath"

Comment: @DanieleTesta Because that flag didn't exist until 2020 (https://github.com/golang/go/commit/79fb187be4d1a1a93c01b3a6be66ea529311ea84) and this answer was written in 2018

Comment: @MTCoster So what I am hearing is that the answer should be updated?